# Rotate video with mp4parser according to the camera used

Tags: java, android, camera, rotation, mp4parser

Basically I would like to *rotate* video, depending on which camera was used to take it.

Front camera is mirrored with 90 degrees, whereas back camera is displayed properly. Currently it will set Matrix according to the first clip. If the first clip was made with front camera, it will rotate all clips to 270 degrees and vice a versa.

Here is a sample code (`rotations` is an *ArrayList* which contains clip rotations):

```
for (TrackBox trackBox : trackBoxes) {
       Log.d("TRACKBOX", String.valueOf(rotations.get(i)));
       //trackBox.getTrackHeaderBox().setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_90);
       if (rotations.get(i) == 90) { //if clip was made with back camera
              trackBox.getTrackHeaderBox().setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_90);
              Log.d("Rotating to:", "90 degrees");

       } else if (rotations.get(i) == 270) { // if clip was made with front camera
              trackBox.getTrackHeaderBox().setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_270);
              Log.d("Rotating to:", "270 degrees");
       }
       m.addTrack(new Mp4TrackImpl(trackBox));

}
inMovies[i] = m;
```

Comment: Hi Torsten, Me to facing same issue. Did you resolve orientation issue? If you resolved issues, Please help me

Comment: @MuraliGanesan I'm sorry but I haven't dealt with this project a long time. I finally used Instagram tactic where you disable switching camera after you've recorded one clip with back/front camera.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you can rotate video with these codes, no need use mp4 parser library, so complex.

```
/**
 *
 * @param mMediaRecorder
 * @return
 */
public static MediaRecorder rotateBackVideo(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder) {
    /**
     * Define Orientation of video in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    switch (CustomCamera.current_orientation) {
        case 0:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            break;
        case 90:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
            break;
        case 180:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            break;
        case 270:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
            break;
    }

    return mMediaRecorder;
}

/**
 *
 * @param mMediaRecorder
 * @return
 */
public static MediaRecorder rotateFrontVideo(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder) {
    /**
     * Define Orientation of video in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    switch (CustomCamera.current_orientation) {
        case 0:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            break;
        case 90:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
            break;
        case 180:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            break;
        case 270:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
            break;
    }

    return mMediaRecorder;
}
```

Comment: How is rotating PHOTO relevant to rotating VIDEO?

Comment: This post could be improved by reading the question first and responding only to the question asked. Rotating photos is totally irrelevant to modifying videos.